# LINQ Filter anonymous type based on IEnumerable values within type

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, anonymous-types

I'm using LINQ to SQL like:

```
var b =  
   from s in context.data  
   select new  
   {   
     id = s.id,  
     name = s.name  
     myEnumerable = s.OneToMany
   };
```

Where myEnumerable is of type `IEnumberable<T>` and I want to now get a subset of `b` based upon properties of the individual items of `myEnumerable`.  For example, say `<T>` has properties `Berry` and `BerryID`, I would want to do something like:

```
b = 
   from p in b
   where //p.myEnumerable.myType.BerryID== 13
   select p;
```

I'm feel like I'm missing something easy...

Comment: Could you clarify your question? You want to filter the collection b again by the collection myEnumerable? What condition do you want to check? myEnumerable contains a item with BerryID == 13? All items must have BerryID == 13?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking to select `p` if any of the items in `p.myEnumerable` have `BerryID` equal to 13?

```
b = from p in b
    where p.myEnumerable.Any(t => t.BerryID == 13)
    select p;
```

Or are you looking to select `p` if *all* of the items in `p.myEnumerable` have `BerryID` equal to 13?

```
b = from p in b
    where p.myEnumerable.All(t => t.BerryID == 13)
    select p;
```

What exactly is the condition you want the items in `p.myEnumerable` to fulfill before you select `p`?

Comment: +1 good call with the Any/All..cleaner looking too than mine.

Answer (score 3):

Since myEnumerable is an IEnumerable you will have to do a where on that.

```
var filteredData = from p in listOfData
                               where p.InnerData.Where(b=>b.ID == 13).Count() > 0
                               select p;
```

If I understand what you are saying...this is if there is an ID = 13 in the Enumerable at all.

Comment: You can shorten Where(condition).Count() to Count(condition). Further Any(condition) is faster then Count(condition) > 0 because Any() can stop after the first positive match while Count() must always process the complete sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Keep only items with at least one item having `BerryID` equal to 13 in the collection.

```
 var b = context.data
     .Where(s => s.OneToMany.Any(i => i.BerryID == 13))
     .Select(s => new { id = s.id, name = s.name, myEnumerable = s.OneToMany });
```

Keep only items with all item having `BerryID` equal to 13 in the collection.

```
 var b = context.data
     .Where(s => s.OneToMany.All(i => i.BerryID == 13))
     .Select(s => new { id = s.id, name = s.name, myEnumerable = s.OneToMany });
```